# How to display Google dougnut chart with array data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a dougnut chart. This chart should take array as data but when I put array, it doesn't show anything. How can create a chart with array data?

**sum.js**

```
...
const arr = [];
    arr.push({
        key: capitalizeEachFirstLetter(value[start].title) + " (%)",
        data: value[start].value1 * 100
    });
    arr.push({
        key: capitalizeEachFirstLetter(value[start + 1].title) + " (%)",
        data: value[start + 1].value1 * 100
    });
    if (end == 5) {
        arr.push({
            key: capitalizeEachFirstLetter(value[start + 2].title) + " (%)",
            data: value[start + 2].value1 * 100
        });
    }
...

    <Chart
       chartType="PieChart"
       data={arr}
       options={pieOption}
       graph_id="PieChart"
       width={'100%'}
       height={'400px'}
       legend_toggle
      />
```

Note: When I give the data like;

```
data={[['Age', 'Weight'], ['a', 12], ['b', 5.5], ['c', 12], ['d', 5.5], ['e', 12], ['f', 5.5]]}
```

it works.

And my data is :

```
[{"title":"TOPLAM DÖNEN VARLIKLAR","value1":0.8099237254874144,"value2":0.6716967762970417},{"title":"TOPLAM DURAN VARLIKLAR","value1":0.19007627451258552,"value2":0.3283032237029582},{"title":"Toplam Kısa Vadeli Yükümlülükler","value1":0.6453778969419264,"value2":0.42796665648321913},{"title":"Toplam Uzun Vadeli Yükümlülükler","value1":0.12545336756938238,"value2":0.15300843856942245},{"title":"TOPLAM ÖZKAYNAKLAR","value1":0.22916873548869124,"value2":0.41902490494735845}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first values in your data "title":"TOPLAM DÖNEN VARLIKLAR" are both text, but according to your code you are attempting to multiply the second value by 100. Is there code that you didn't post that is handling the text so that it doesn't attempt to multiply the text?

Have you tried pushing your first example data into the array builder the same way that you're trying to push in your second example data because the two sets of data are in different formats.